# application is closing just after first launch

Tags: xcode4, xcodebuild, adhoc, ios-provisioning

I have build signed the iPhone application with Adhoc provisioning profile,after installing the application directly through Xcode it launched and then closed. I want to know this is correct behavior or something is wrong in my source code?
I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.6 version of Mac OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following :

- restart xCode
- ensure the adHoc provisioning profile is properly installed on the device using the Organizer.
- do a clean & build
- use the organizer summary panel to add application on your device.
- if still failing, please try to restart your device.
- if still failing, provide us logs you might have within the console.

Hope this helps.