# iPhone App Ad Hoc Distribution Issue - "Failed to sync"

Tags: iphone, xcode, distribution, signing

Just getting back into iPhone dev after almost two years off (last dev'd on iOS3) and I'm getting grief while trying to do an ad hoc distribution.

I:

- Added new devices in the provisioning portal (inc. my own to test)
- Recreated my ad hoc provisioning profile
- Installed it in Xcode
- Updated the target to use it and built the app (no problem so far)
- Dragged the app and profile into iTunes
- Sync'd
- Got the message "Failed to sync"

Knowing that this was likely an issue with the profile I started from scratch and:

- Removed the old profile
- Recreated my certificate
- Recreated the profile
- Completed the above steps
- Got the same result

I'm not 100% sure of my target and build settings. Here are screen shots of the relevant sections in case it helps:

*Target Code Signing (the correct profile is selected):*
[image: Target Code Signing]

*Project Configuration:*
[image: Project Configuration]

I've been advised in another post to refer to the documentation but I have been unable to locate specific information on these settings. I still have doco on how to do it in Xcode 3.x but it doesn't sdeem to be doing me much good here.

Thanks in advance,

Alan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thanks to you Sebastian. Your post didn't directly answer my issue but switching to using the Organiser got me one step further and finally led me to a post that pointed out the critical detail:

***Can be debugged*** must be set to NO for ad hoc distributions in Entitlements.plist

That was my problem and I have now successfully installed after making the change.

Answer (score 1):

See a previous post of mine related to [AdHoc application deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996237/application-is-closing-just-after-first-launch/6996566#6996566).

I guess the way to do it properly, is to use the Organizer and not iTunes Sync.

Note about your screenshots : The only issue I noticed is the ***Code Signing Identity*** in Debug should use *debug provisioning profile* and not *distribution* one.

Hope this helps.